# Two bibliographies with two different styles in the same document

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

When using `biblatex`, suppose I have set up two separate bibliographies, how can I assign them different styles, e.g. one numbered and the other author-year format or some such thing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\cite{A01,B02}

\printbibliography[title={References},category=cited]

\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 30):

Good question. :-) One the one hand, section 3.6.2 of the `biblatex` manual mentions

> mixing a numerical subbibliography
>   with one or more subbibliographies
>   using a different scheme (e. g.,
>   author-title or author-year).

On the other hand, according to section 3.1.1, `style`, `bibstyle` and `citestyle` are load-time options, i.e. they must be specified when `biblatex` is loaded and cannot be used in the optional argument of `\printbibliography`.

I have a possibly hackish solution. Load `biblatex` with a `numeric` style (the default behaviour) or an `alphabetic` style. Define a new bibliography environment `nolabelbib` that simply copies the definition of `bibliography` as found in `authortitle.bbx` and `authoryear.bbx` (i.e. one that doesn't print a label). Switch to this environment for your "Further Reading" (sub-)bibliography. The result should equate the `authortitle` style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

% The following definition is copied from authortitle.bbx/authoryear.bbx
\defbibenvironment{nolabelbib}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography[title={References},category=cited]

\printbibliography[env=nolabelbib,title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, biblatex never stops to amaze me.

Comment: I've tried to compile this example with

``pdflatex file.tex``
``bibtex file``
``pdflatex file.tex``
``pdflatex file.tex``

But no bibliography was generated. How could I compile correctly the example? Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved with

``\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,useprefix,hyperref,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}``

Comment: This is also perfect for adding a global bibliography with a different style to per-section bibliographies. Just define the `nolabelbib` environment in preamble, open a new refcontext (with your preferred sorting option) for your global biblio, `\nocite{*}` (possibly to gether with the `cited` macro), and call upon the environment at the global `\printbibliography`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you do this the same way now?

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out the `multibib` library:

http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/multibib/multibib.pdf

Comment: The question is about `biblatex` so `multibib` is irrelevant. Biblatex already allows multiple bibliographies and cannot be used with such auxiliary packages.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah But the OP's example can't be redone using `multibib` if it is using things like `category`, can it? It's also debatable whether `multibib` is preferable given the other advantages of `biblatex`, but that will obviously depend on the details.