# Small bibliography inside a document with its own bibliography

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

A document (class article) has a bibliography (using biblatex) printed at the end. But inside the document, a small section (call included section in my example) has its own bibliography (not part of the main bibliography) which is printed at the end of the included section. This small sectop, has no citations to the main bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  category = {internal}
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{internal}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\addtocategory{internal}{A01}

\section{first section}

blabla~\cite{B02}


\section{included section}

blabla~\cite{A01}

\printbibliography[title={bibliography of included section},category=internal]

\section{other sections...}

blabla~\cite{C03}

\printbibliography[title={Full bibliography without internal category},notcategory=internal]

\end{document}
```

The PDF is the following:

[image: PDF]

The main problem is that the included bibliography is part of the main bibliography: the main bibliography starts at [2], because it contains the bibliography of the included section. How can i (logicaly) separate the two bibliography ? I want the small bibliography to used references like '[Babar2007]' and the main bibliography to be numbered like "[23]" (with its own reference counter: main bibliography starts at 1) ?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is [Two bibliographies with two different styles in the same document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104) of any help?

Comment: I think this is a dupe: please edit and ask for reopening if I've missed something.

Comment: I don't think so: the link you mentionned was about changing the style of two bibliographies based on category, mine was about including an isolated bubliography inside a whole document with its own bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a `refsection` environment. (I used `bibtex` as the backend.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  category = {internal}
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{internal}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\addtocategory{internal}{A01}

\section{first section}
\begin{refsection}

blabla~\cite{B02}


\section{included section}

blabla~\cite{A01}

\printbibliography[title={bibliography of included section},category=internal]
\end{refsection}

\section{other sections...}

blabla~\cite{C03}

\printbibliography[title={Full bibliography without internal category},notcategory=internal]

\end{document}
```

Note that you must run `bibtex` on all auxiliary files:

```
bibtex tmp1-blx.aux
bibte  tmp2-blx.aux
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: I have tried this solution but I didn't know for the double bibtex calls... Let me check...

Comment: It works, so my mistake was really about the double call to bibtex, thank you.