# Roman numerals in citation with cite package

Tags: citing, cite-package

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79599/38244) example, I am using `\usepackage{cite}`. Now, I need all my citations are marked by Roman numerals. This is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @Article{art1,
        author =   {Author, A. N.},
        title =    {Title One},
        journal =  {Journal},
        year =     2000
    }

    @Article{art2,
        author =   {Author, A. N.},
        title =    {Title Two},
        journal =  {Journal},
        year =     2008
    }
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

    Refering to second article\cite{art2} and then first article\cite{art1}

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

I have found several questions like this, such as [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151963/separate-bibliography-in-roman-numerals-citeable-everywhere), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350186/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-roman-and-arabic-numbering), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139944/subbibliography-with-roman-numbers-and-biblatex?noredirect=1&lq=1); but all of them use `biblatex`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the bibliography

```
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{[\romannumeral 0#1]}
```

should work (of course within `\makeatletter...\makeatother`).

Without `hyperref` you could use

```
\renewcommand\citeform[1]{\romannumeral 0#1}
```

for the citations as suggested in the `cite` manual. Unfortunately, `hyperref` turns the argument of `\citeform` into an unexpandable link, so the formatting can't be applied at this late stage. With `hyperref` interfering I could get things to work by redefining `\bibcite`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\bibcite#1#2{%
  \@newl@bel{b}{#1\@extra@binfo}{%
    \hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1\@extra@b@citeb}{\romannumeral 0#2}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{[\romannumeral 0#1]}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{art1,
  author  = {Author, A. N.},
  title   = {Title One},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = 2000
}

@Article{art2,
  author  = {Author, A. N.},
  title   = {Title Two},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = 2008
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
  Refering to second article\cite{art2} and then first article\cite{art1}

  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

As the eagle-eyed will have spotted the margin is off because the margin width calculation is done on the BibTeX side assuming arabic numerals.

[image: Citations and bibliography show the number in lowercase Roman numerals.]

---

The `llncs.cls` class you use redefines `\@biblabel` directly in its definition of `thebibliography`, we can only counter this by redefining the entire environment

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}
      \renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{[\romannumeral 0##1]}%
      \small
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \if@openbib
              \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
              \itemindent -\bibindent
              \listparindent \itemindent
              \parsep \z@
            \fi
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \if@openbib
        \renewcommand\newblock{\par}%
      \else
        \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
      \fi
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.=\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Comment: In the References, the bib items are still coming in Arabic. I am using `splncs_src.bst` [https://github.com/tvcutsem/es-lab/blob/master/doc/esop13/splncs_srt.bst] with `llncs`. May be, that is causing the problem.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Where can I get `llncs.cls`? This should be caused by the document class and not by the `.bst` file?

Comment: @pushpen.paul I have edited the answer with a workaround for `llncs.cls` from https://www.springer.com/de/it-informatik/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines

Comment: It took me half an hour figuring this. In a nutshell, if you don't use `hyperref`, use `\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{[\romannumeral 0#1]}` AND `\renewcommand\citeform[1]{\romannumeral 0#1}`. If you use hyperref, look at the complete code.