# Use Roman numerals for inline citation in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

I'm using the code from [Roman numerals in citation with cite package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452752/roman-numerals-in-citation-with-cite-package).

I want to use letters, a, b, c to denote the inline citation and the bibliography.

[image]

I tested my code in the article documentclass. It worked fine. But when I use it in beamer, the code fails to work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}


\usepackage{cite}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{[\@alph{0#1}]}
\renewcommand\citeform[1]{\@alph{0#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\meaning\cite

Refering to second article~\cite{ciccozzi2019execution}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibliography/slides.bib}
\end{document}
```

It's not required to use the cite package.

I guess beamer renews the cite command therefore my renew of citeform didn't kick in.

I'm keen to learn how to debug this kind of problem, I used [`\meaning\cite`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/display-source-for-a-command), which didn't give me anything interesting.

Besides, can anyone give a fix?