# Use roman numerals for cite in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, roman-numerals

I'm using BibLaTeX for my bibliography, with the the following options:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8, citestyle=numeric, defernumbers=true, bibstyle=numeric, autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
```

I would like to know how I could use roman numerals instead of arabic numerals for enumerating bibliography entries. I have already found [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139944/subbibliography-with-roman-numbers-and-biblatex), but the answer doesn't entirely suit my needs.

What I want is something like this:

> Some text. [I]
>
> ## Bibliography
>
> [I] The corresponding reference.

Instead of this:

> Some text. [1]
>
> ## Bibliography
>
> [1] The corresponding reference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be enough to have

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\Rn{#1}}
```

for lowercase numerals, or

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\RN{#1}}
```

for uppercase numerals.

If a `shorthand` is present it is used instead of a number, but still the `labelnumber` format seems to apply, so something like

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifinteger{#1}{\RN{#1}}{#1}}
```

is a bit safer.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\RN{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,wilde,worman,knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: picture of MWE output]

---

Since `biblatex` version 3.1 and more specifically commit [`e5c2826`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/e5c28262e3633b001af2fe4bee97d3c2d18e28ae) the fix previously contained in this answer is obsolete; it has been removed (but can be of course be found in the revision history).

Comment: I have added a bug report [(#342)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/342) about the labelnumberwidth calculation.

Comment: Thanks to @moewe for the bug report - this width issue will be fixed in the next biblatex release.