# Citing references by the label

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have a document with a list of references that I would like enumerated alphabetically, e.g.:

```
A.  Document ABCD by Tom Bloggins
B.  Article WXYZ by Bill Shawinigan
C.  Etc.
```

And I would like to cite them in the text as follows:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (Ref A), consectetur adipiscing elit (Ref B), etc. etc.
```

How can I achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{astronaut}
A. Chris Hatfield, "I'm Awesome"
\end{thebibliography}
\section{Introduction}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \cite{astronaut}, consectetur adipiscing elit, etc. etc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How did you produce the bibliography/ordered references? What bibliography packages (if any) are you using, what style? Please consider adding a short [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to your question so we can see what you see.

Comment: I don't understand.  How could I post a minimal working example of something I don't know how to do?

Comment: I suspect that with "ordered alphabetically" you actually mean sorted in citation order and numbered by letters. Please clarify this point.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17409/36296

Comment: Demanding working code for what you want would indeed be absurd, but the request for an MWE was of course only about what you have so far. You mentioned that you already have your references and so it was important to know how you produced these (as there are several ways to produce a bibliography in LaTeX). A solution depends on your current setup.

Comment: I'll happily change anything required to get citations and bibliography the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my inspiration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271551/75648) and with a little help from Stephan I found a package that might suit your needs.

If by enumerated alphabetically you mean **alphanumeric references** then this should solve your problem (keep scrolling down).

If however you need them to be alphabetically sorted then just use :

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

or

```
\usepackage[style=nty]{biblatex}
```

Depending on your preference.

Now to the alphanumeric sorting:

[image: alphanumeric reference]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{alphalph} %This package allows you to convert numbers to letters alphabetically.
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\AlphAlph{#1}} % this command is to redefine the label. 
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{astronaut,
    author = {A. Chris Hatfield},
    title = {I'm Awesome}
}
@article{cosmonaut,
    author = {John. Jack Hatfield},
    title = {You Awesome}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography

\section{Introduction}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \cite{astronaut}, consectetur adipiscing elit, \cite{cosmonaut} etc. etc. 
\end{document}
```

If this answers your question, remember to check the green V :).