# Biblatex: displaying title before author in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm creating a document that includes two separate bibliographies, which must be formatted differently. I found lockstep's excellent answer on question 10104 ( [Two bibliographies with two different styles in the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/two-bibliographies-with-two-different-styles-in-the-same-document) ), and I'm already using it.

I have loaded the authoryear bibliography style for the main bibliography. But the second bibliography must be formatted with the title before the author name.

Any suggestion on how to implement this?

Comment: This will require redefinition of the `BibliographyDriver` for each bib type in the style you desire.  What is the base style of the second bibliography?  Which types do you need (book, article...)?

Comment: Also, it is best to include your own MWE (see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3301/47522)), even though you are branching off of a previous question.  Your own needs are somewhat different than the original.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks, @cslstr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this exhaustively, and it probably doesn't work for some crazier titles with `@inbook` with `booktitle` or other extras that are similar.

Basically, I have added a flag that checks when we are in the bibliography where it is desired to have the title appear first.  Then for those `bibitems`, we add a new title `bibmacro` to the beginning of the entry, and clear out the original title `bibmacro`.  For other items with extra title fields, you may have to clear other fields out as well, depending on how you want it to work.  (Some entry types don't use `\usebibmacro{title}`, but use `\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}`, for example; this does not take that into account.)

I added a few extra entries to demonstrate use.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For boolean flags

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

% Boolean flags to detect environment
\newbool{titlefirst}
% The following definition is copied from authortitle.bbx/authoryear.bbx
\defbibenvironment{nolabelbib}
  {\booltrue{titlefirst}\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist\boolfalse{titlefirst}}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\nocite{C03,companion,worman,piccato,aristotle:physics}

% Enable sort by title
\DeclareSortingScheme{titleauthor}{
\sort{\field{sorttitle}\field{title}}
\sort{\field{author}\field{editor}\field{translator}}}

% Redefine titlefirst to be the same as the original title from biblatex.def
\newbibmacro*{titlefirst}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

% Each bibitem, check if we're in titlefirst env
% If so, put a title at the beginning, clear original title bibmacro
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \ifbool{titlefirst}{
    \renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\usebibmacro{titlefirst}\newunit}
    \renewbibmacro*{title}{} % Clear original title bibmacro
  }
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography[title={References},category=cited]

\printbibliography[env=nolabelbib,sorting=titleauthor,title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]

% Print the first bibliography again to be sure we haven't ruined
% Something permanantly
\printbibliography[title={References},category=cited]

\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography]

Comment: Great! It worked like a charm. Thanks, @cslstr.