# Independent publication list with numbered list using biblatex and refsection

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I would like to add a list of publications to a thesis ordered by the publication date and numbered 1,2,3. Additionally the author of the thesis should be highlighted bold in this list.

The approach I tried is to use a refsection with a modified `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` and `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}`. This works in principle, but the numbering is according to the bibliography (what I do not want) and not the list index. The numbering can be independent by using the option `defernumbers` but then the number never starts at one. In this example it would be 4,5,6. 
A minor error is that each list start with a space instead of the authors name.
The normal bibliography is with a different style (alphabetic) and must remain unchanged.

If the numbered refsection with numbers according to the list index is not possible the second qustion would still be open. I want the thesis writers name in the list of publications to be highlighted (bold). In this case I have no idea how to achieve that.

This image shows how the numbering is wrong:

[image]

This is an example one can work on:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic, % Loads the bibliography and the citation style 
  %style=numeric,
]{biblatex}  

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
sorting=nty, % Sort by name, title, year.
maxbibnames=15,%
%defernumbers,
}%      

\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
@Article{Pospiech2010,
  Title                    = {Single-sweep laser writing of 3D-waveguide devices},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Benjamin V\"{a}ckenstedt and Guido Palmer and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {7},
  Pages                    = {6994--7001},
  Volume                   = {18},
}

@Article{Pospiech2009,
  Title                    = {Double waveguide couplers produced by simultaneous femtosecond writing},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Andy Steinmann and Guido Palmer and Roberto Osellame and Nicola Bellini and Giulio Cerullo and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2009},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {3555--3563},
  Volume                   = {17},
}

@Article{Siegel2007,
  Title                    = {Theoretical and experimental limits of cavity-dumping in passively mode-locked thin-disk oscillators},
  Author                   = {Martin Siegel and Guido Palmer and Andy Steinmann and Matthias Pospiech and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2007},
  Month                    = {Dec},
  Number                   = {25},
  Pages                    = {16860--16869},
  Volume                   = {15},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\numberedreferences}{%
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}.%
        }%
     }%
  {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
   \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
   \addtolength{\labelsep}{1em}
   \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
   % fails to compile if included
   %\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}
  }
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
}%

\section*{Scientific publications}
\begin{refsection}[publications]%
\numberedreferences
\nocite{*}
% supposed to be numbered and with author highlighted (bold)
\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ynt]
\end{refsection}

% standard style
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography    

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
This code show how the code from the examples below fails if parts are wrapped in a conditional:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{biblatex}  
\usepackage{xpatch}

\IfPackageLoaded{biblatex}{%

% \boldnames: etoolbox-list of names to typeset bold in \printbibiliography
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\ifstrequal{#1, #2}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}}

\xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}

%
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last}

}% \IfPackageLoaded{biblatex}

\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
@Article{Pospiech2010,
  Title                    = {Single-sweep laser writing of 3D-waveguide devices},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Benjamin V\"{a}ckenstedt and Guido Palmer and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {7},
  Pages                    = {6994--7001},
  Volume                   = {18},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{refsection}%
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ynt, resetnumbers=true] %env=numbered+bold, 
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@do 
                   {Pospiech2009}\blx@listloop@i
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/181407/39222, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170358/39222, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34827/39222, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174229/39222, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10104/39222

Comment: Perhaps you could adapt [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170534/39222)? [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10106/39222) suggests there is not likely to be a non-hackish solution...

Comment: Maybe this Q&A can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183500/define-a-bibliography-environment/183772

Comment: Most of these answers are not helpful directly, but the idea in most of them is to modify style commands, which I have now tried here. However the code fails to compile if put in a separate command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biblatex` package allows to have independent numbering schemes for differents `refsections`. To get truly independent numbering in different bibliographies, you also need to pass the `resetnumbers=true` option to each additional `\printbibliography` command (in addition to the `defernumbers` option you already passed to the package). Note however, that you may **need 3 to 4 compilation runs** for the list to be correctly numbered.

```
\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ynt, resetnumbers=true]
```

Additionally, in your command the following code fails to compile:

```
   % fails to compile if included
   \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}
```

The reason is that you're including a `\defbibenvironment` (which defines an environment) into your `\newcommand` definition. Thus, the `##1` argument being passed in `\renewcommand` is not the argument passed to `\defbibenvironment` (as it should) but rather the (non-existing) argument passed to `\newcommand`.

Luckily, you don't need to create a new command in order to apply a new bibliography style, you can simply create a new bibliography environment and pass it to `\printbibliography`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\newlength{\periodwidth}
\settowidth{\periodwidth}{.}

\defbibenvironment{numbered+bold}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}%
        }%
     }%
  {
   \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
   \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
   \addtolength{\labelsep}{1em}
   \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
   \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}%
  }
  {\endlist}
  {\item\hskip-\periodwidth}
```

Once defined, it can be used like so:

```
\printbibliography[env=numbered+bold, heading=none, sorting=ynt, resetnumbers=true]
```

Note that I also corrected the indentation of the list of authors. The additional space before the authors is due to changing from the `alphabetic` to the `numeric` style mid-document. From my understanding, this is not encouraged nor supported by `biblatex` and it seems that even though you can successfully change the bibliography to use numeric labels, some side-effects from the `alphabetic` style remain. I have not been able to track where this extra space is added, but a possible workaround is to add a negative horizontal space which equals the length of the period character being used.

Making a specific author name bold has already been covered by [Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187181/independent-publication-list-with-numbered-list-using-biblatex-and-refsection/187530#187530). Note however that this **is independent of the new environment we created**. If you fill the list again with `\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}{{Pospiech, Matthias}, {Pospiech, M.}}` before calling the last `printbibliography`, it will also mark the author in bold for that bibliography.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic, % Loads the bibliography and the citation style 
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}  

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  sorting=nty, % Sort by name, title, year.
  maxbibnames=15,%
}%      

\addbibresource{publications.bib}

% Emphasize own name in References with boldface
\usepackage{xpatch}

% \boldnames: etoolbox-list of names to typeset bold in \printbibiliography
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\ifstrequal{#1, #2}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}}


\xpretobibmacro{name:last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:first-last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:first-last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
@Article{Pospiech2010,
  Title                    = {Single-sweep laser writing of 3D-waveguide devices},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Benjamin V\"{a}ckenstedt and Guido Palmer and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {7},
  Pages                    = {6994--7001},
  Volume                   = {18},
}

@Article{Pospiech2009,
  Title                    = {Double waveguide couplers produced by simultaneous femtosecond writing},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Andy Steinmann and Guido Palmer and Roberto Osellame and Nicola Bellini and Giulio Cerullo and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2009},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {3555--3563},
  Volume                   = {17},
}

@Article{Siegel2007,
  Title                    = {Theoretical and experimental limits of cavity-dumping in passively mode-locked thin-disk oscillators},
  Author                   = {Martin Siegel and Guido Palmer and Andy Steinmann and Matthias Pospiech and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2007},
  Month                    = {Dec},
  Number                   = {25},
  Pages                    = {16860--16869},
  Volume                   = {15},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\newlength{\periodwidth}
\settowidth{\periodwidth}{.}

\defbibenvironment{numbered+bold}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}%
        }%
     }%
  {
   \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
   \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
   \addtolength{\labelsep}{1em}
   \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
   \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}%
  }
  {\endlist}
  {\item\hskip-\periodwidth}

\section*{Scientific publications}
\begin{refsection}[publications]%

\nocite{*}
% supposed to be numbered and with author highlighted (bold)
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}{{Pospiech, Matthias}, {Pospiech, M.}}
\printbibliography[env=numbered+bold, heading=none, sorting=ynt, resetnumbers=true]
\end{refsection}

% standard style
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography    

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I also added a screenshot of the resulting bibliographies:

[image: shot]

Comment: Very nice code, however the bold part files in my code, see the additional text in the question.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech interesting, maybe it would be better to create a new question for that particular issue, since it seems to be a problem with the patch commands

Comment: I now got every thing to work in my thesis template. However I had to remove the ´\hskip-\periodwidth´ to get indentation correct.

Comment: Glad that you got everything working :)

Comment: The solution doesn't work anymore with `biblatex 2016/03/03 v3.3`. Is there any fix to get it working with the udated version?

Comment: I can also add that it does not work anymore with 3.11.

Answer (score 3):

The following provides a solution for the **bold author** and the counting issue.

Most of the code that implements the bold author feature origins from this site; however, I am currently not able to find the original source to give credit to it :-(

---

**Edit:** The bold author code was originally provided by user [Audry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey) in his answer to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex)

---

The workaround for the numbering in your *Scientific Publications* section is to just replace the `\printfield{labelnumer}` with an own counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic, % Loads the bibliography and the citation style 
  %style=numeric,
]{biblatex}  

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
sorting=nty, % Sort by name, title, year.
maxbibnames=15,%
%defernumbers,
}%      

\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}


% Emphasize own name in References with boldface
\usepackage{xpatch}% or use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705

% \boldnames: etoolbox-list of names to typeset bold in \printbibiliography
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\ifstrequal{#1, #2}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}}


\xpretobibmacro{name:last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:first-last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:first-last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last}




\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
@Article{Pospiech2010,
  Title                    = {Single-sweep laser writing of 3D-waveguide devices},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Benjamin V\"{a}ckenstedt and Guido Palmer and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {7},
  Pages                    = {6994--7001},
  Volume                   = {18},
}

@Article{Pospiech2009,
  Title                    = {Double waveguide couplers produced by simultaneous femtosecond writing},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Andy Steinmann and Guido Palmer and Roberto Osellame and Nicola Bellini and Giulio Cerullo and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2009},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {3555--3563},
  Volume                   = {17},
}

@Article{Siegel2007,
  Title                    = {Theoretical and experimental limits of cavity-dumping in passively mode-locked thin-disk oscillators},
  Author                   = {Martin Siegel and Guido Palmer and Andy Steinmann and Matthias Pospiech and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2007},
  Month                    = {Dec},
  Number                   = {25},
  Pages                    = {16860--16869},
  Volume                   = {15},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\numberedreferences}{%
\newcount\mycount

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \global\advance\mycount 1
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \the\mycount.%
        }%
     }%
  {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
   \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
   \addtolength{\labelsep}{1em}
   \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
   % fails to compile if included
   %\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}
  }
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
}%

\section*{Scientific publications}
\begin{refsection}[publications]%
\numberedreferences
\nocite{*}
% supposed to be numbered and with author highlighted (bold)
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{Pospiech, Matthias}, {Pospiech, M.}}
\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ynt]
\end{refsection}

% standard style
\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can you just put a square (like itemize) in stead of the number for the Scientific publications? And to change the main option of maxnumber of authors?

Comment: Although I do not understand the code completely it works fine in your example. I do however wrap the definition code in a condition with `\IfPackageLoaded{biblatex}{% ... }%` which is defined as `\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}`. If I do that I get the error `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \blx@do                   {Pospiech2009}\blx@listloop@i`.

Comment: I added a MWE for this error in the question.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: The command definitions inside the block and its use of arguments cannot be passed "as is" to the argument of another macro (your `\IfPackageLoaded`). A simple solution would be to just use a TeX conditional: `\newif\ifbiblatex` `\IfPackageLoaded{biblatex}{\biblatextrue}`. Then wrap the conditional part with `\ifbiblatex` and `\fi`

Comment: Thanks, egreg had another idea: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188188/loop-macro-fails-if-wrapped-in-conditional.