# loop macro fails if wrapped in conditional

Tags: biblatex, errors, loops

The following code is a subset of the answer in  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187181/independent-publication-list-with-numbered-list-using-biblatex-and-refsection). The code provided in the answer works fine, but fails if I add a conditional `\IfPackageLoaded`. I post this error as a new question, because it has not necessarily to do with the original question.

The problem has to do with the sequence `\xpretobibmacro` although I have no idea why.
The failure message is below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{biblatex}  
\usepackage{xpatch}

\IfPackageLoaded{biblatex}{%

% \boldnames: etoolbox-list of names to typeset bold in \printbibiliography
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\ifstrequal{#1, #2}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}}

\xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}

%
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last}

}% \IfPackageLoaded{biblatex}

\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
@Article{Pospiech2010,
  Title                    = {Single-sweep laser writing of 3D-waveguide devices},
  Author                   = {Matthias Pospiech and Moritz Emons and Benjamin V\"{a}ckenstedt and Guido Palmer and Uwe Morgner},
  Journal                  = {Opt. Express},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {7},
  Pages                    = {6994--7001},
  Volume                   = {18},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{refsection}%
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ynt, resetnumbers=true] %env=numbered+bold, 
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@do 
                   {Pospiech2009}\blx@listloop@i
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `xpatch` (or the original commands in `etoolbox`) for patching macros, it's recommended to use the builtin diagnostics, that is `\tracingpatches` and the “fail” argument.

If you add `\tracingpatches` to the preamble, before your usage of `\IfPackageLoaded`, you'll get the message

```
[debug] tracing \pretocmd on input line 26
[debug] analyzing '\abx@macro@name:last-first'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro with parameters
[debug] -- nested patching command and parameters in patch
[debug] -> the patching command seems to be nested in the
[debug]    argument to some other command
[debug] -> the patch text seems to contain # characters
[debug] -> either avoid nesting or use # characters with
[debug]    category code 12 in the patch text
[debug] -> simply doubling the # characters will not work
```

and if you add `\ddt` to the “fail” argument (or any undefined control sequence), TeX will stop, meaning that the patch has failed. The message explains what goes wrong: one can't use the `#` token in the arguments of `\patchcmd`, `\pretocmd` or `\apptocmd` and the derived `xpatch` commands when the patching appears in the argument to another command, in this case `\IfPackageLoaded`.

In this case `etoolbox` suggests a workaround: use `#` with category code 12:

```
\IfPackageLoaded{biblatex}{%
  % \boldnames: etoolbox-list of names to typeset bold in \printbibiliography
  \newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
  \newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
    \def\do##1{\ifstrequal{#1, #2}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
    \dolistloop{\boldnames}}
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#\lowercase{\endgroup
    \xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{?1}{?2}}{}{}%
  }
  \xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}
  %
  \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last}
}
```

Using the `\lowercase` trick works because, happily, all the character tokens in the arguments to `\xpretobibmacro` command are lowercase. Uppercase characters would need appropriate declarations such as

```
\lccode`A=`A
```

next to `` \lccode`?=`# ``.

---

By the way, I find misnamed the `\IfPackageLoaded` command: All `\@if...` or `\If...` commands I know of have arguments both for the “true” and “false” cases. Probably `\DoIfPackageLoaded` would be a better name.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. BTW: My package templatetools defines several commands that work that way.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech You're not giving users the chance of doing "something else" if the package is not loaded.