# Using three different reference lists in one document with different citation styles

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I try to include three different reference lists into one article, all using different citation styles, like e.g. in this mini layout example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

We have regular References, like e.g. Hamburger (1995), but also still [1],[2] and the third one [R1].

\section{Other references}
\hangindent+25pt \hangafter=1
[1] Meyer, D.: Really, really interesting stuff, it's a must read. Publ. Int. Stu. \textbf{112}, 1--21 (2014)\\

\noindent
\hangindent+25pt \hangafter=1
[2] Smith, D.: Even more interesting stuff than Meyer has. Publ. Int. Stu. \textbf{122}, 1--21 (2014)\\

\noindent
\hangindent+25pt \hangafter=1
[R1] Smith, D.: One can make even an R-package from that stuff. Publ. Int. Comp. \textbf{1}, 21--41 (2014)

\section{References}
\hangindent+25pt \hangafter=1
Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura. Appl. \textbf{169}, 321--354 (1995)

\end{document}
```

Of course, I could hard-code the entire reference list as in the layout example above, but is there any way to use a `\cite` command with tailored bst files? I tried also the `multibib` library, but this only adds prefixes to all different reference lists, by using e.g. `\citeR`,... with `\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}` resulting in reference lists like

```
[A1] ...
[A2] ...

[R1] ...

[C1] ...
```

What I would need is an option in multibib that avoids the numbering for one sublist entirely (dropping the `C1`), for one it should use only consecutive numbers (dropping the `A`s) and for the third it should add a prefix like it is in `R1`.

Is there any alternative to multibib that could do the trick? Or is there any way of tailoring three bst files for multibib so that the three references lists look like I want them to be?

Comment: If you're still wondering about this, perhaps you've discovered `biblatex`, and this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/two-bibliographies-with-two-different-styles-in-the-same-document?noredirect=1&lq=1