# multiple styles in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to use multiple styles in my bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Is there a way to combine both? LaTeX only chooses the first option when compiling the document...

Comment: Possibly interesting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/two-bibliographies-with-two-different-styles-in-the-same-document

Answer (score 1):

What bibliography package are you using? biblatex? jurabib? natbib?

Have a look at [biblatex (manual, section 3.3.1)](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for a description of out of the box styles that can be used. I think the first two might be interesting for you.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer!

Comment: Yes, but @HATEthePLOT can not yet comment because of his low reputation.