# Change biblatex style locally in refsection

Tags: biblatex, biber

In the thesis that I am writing, I use biblatex with biber as the backend to print a list of references after each chapter and a global bibliography at the end. In the beginning of the document I need a list of my own publications.
For the overall bibliography I want to use the `phys` style without article titles. However, for the list of my own publications I need a more detailed list that includes for example the title. Currently (see MWE) I have a `refsection` that references the publications in question with `nocite` after which the `printbibliography` provides me with the desired list. How can I now change the style such, that this list and this list only in the document prints the title in the `printbibliography` command?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{main.bib}
@article{refA,
  title = {Title A},
  author = {A. Author},
  journal = {Journal A},
  year = {2016},
}
@article{refB,
  title = {Title B},
  author = {B. Booker},
  journal = {Journal B},
  year = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, articletitle=false, biblabel=brackets, pageranges=false, block=ragged]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{refA}
    \nocite{refB}
    \defbibnote{lop_prescript}{
        The work presented in this thesis is based on the following publications
    }
    \defbibnote{lop_postscript}{
        Some publications are currently under peer review
    }
    \printbibliography[
        segment=\therefsegment,
        heading=bibintoc,
        title={List of Publications},
        prenote=lop_prescript,
        postnote=lop_postscript
    ]
\end{refsection}

\section{Some section}
This would be the main content, e.g. chapters where references are cited\cite{refB}.

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know `\printbibliography` does not recognize the `style` key. In any case that is the error telling me that I am getting

Comment: You are right, my bad. But I've found this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/two-bibliographies-with-two-different-styles-in-the-same-document

Comment: It will never be possible to arbitrarily switch styles in a document - the styles determine too many possible things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no general method to change a style. But in many simple cases it it possible to do it by looking at the code.  In your case the title is handled by a simple boolean that you can switch locally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{main.bib}
@article{refA,
  title = {Title A},
  author = {A. Author},
  journal = {Journal A},
  year = {2016},
}
@article{refB,
  title = {Title B},
  author = {B. Booker},
  journal = {Journal B},
  year = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, articletitle=false, biblabel=brackets, pageranges=false, block=ragged]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\settoggle{bbx:articletitle}{true}%
    \nocite{refA}
    \nocite{refB}
    \defbibnote{lop_prescript}{
        The work presented in this thesis is based on the following publications
    }
    \defbibnote{lop_postscript}{
        Some publications are currently under peer review
    }
    \printbibliography[
        segment=\therefsegment,
        heading=bibintoc,
        title={List of Publications},
        prenote=lop_prescript,
        postnote=lop_postscript
    ]
\end{refsection}

\section{Some section}
This would be the main content, e.g. chapters where references are cited\cite{refB}.

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. I have been working with latex and related tools for several years now and I feel comfortable with many programming languages, but I have never really grokked the TeX family and feel completely lost if I need to customize anything. This is also largely due to the fact that I do not yet know how to do targeted searches in the often overly detailed manuals. Maybe someday...