# Double bibliography with biblatex: at the end of each chapter, and at the end of the document

Tags: biblatex

I'm facing so many troubles to get my bibliographies properly, so maybe one of you guys can help me to find out the way. The idea is to have a separate bibliography at the end of each chapter with the following requisites:

- Entries numbered and begining with [1].
- Entries sorted according to their order of appearance.
- Same entry may appear in different chapters; in that case, each instance of the same entry must have a different numbering according to its order of appearance.

Also, at the end of the document there must be another bibliography with some different characteristics:

- Entries sorted alphabetically by author's name.
- All entries cited within document must appear in this bibliography.
- The page number where the entry has been cited must be included (something like "cited in page XX").
- This bibliography must appear in TOC.

I'm using `biblatex` and, so far, I cannot get the proper citation numbering at each chapter (if a work has been previously cited in another chapter it keeps its reference number despite I set `resetnumbers=true`), and I'm not able to change the style to get rid of numbers at the end bibliography.

My minimal working example is as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{ref1,
title = {An experimental study},
year = {2000},
author = {Smith, M}
}
@article{ref2,
title = {Analysis of topics},
year = {2005},
author = {Johnson, B}
}
@article{ref3,
title = {Methodological review},
year = {2010},
author = {Thompson, R}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee,refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\cite{ref1} is a new reference and \cite{ref2} as well.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\cite{ref3} is again a new reference that must be numbered as one, while \cite{ref1} first appeared with number one in the previous chapter. Now it must show the number two in the following bibliography.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true]

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,sorting=nty]

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `biblatex` can't do that out of the box (as far as I know), so a little hacking is required. Here's what I've done:

1. Use `refsection` instead of `refsegment` to make the bibliographies completely independent for every chapter. This has an unfortunate consequence that `biblatex` completely forgets about references from previous chapters.
2. To print the final bibliography I had to introduce another refsection (hence the `\newrefsection` command), and use `\nocite{}` to include all citations from all the chapters. Since maintaining this list of references manually would be error prone, I've (by a suggestion in comments) added some code to the cite key hook to append the current label to a global references list, and then I've used this list as the argument for `\nocite`.
3. To suppress numbering in the final bibliography I've used the answer [from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/two-bibliographies-with-two-different-styles-in-the-same-document) and created a special environment copied from the authortitle style file.
4. Another bit is a pretty dirty trick with patching an internal `biblatex` command `\bbl@addbackref@i` for backreferences in the main bibliography. It saves the current refsection and some other info to enable backreferencing. So instead of the current, I need it to store the last refsection, which in turn is to be saved by the new `\saverefsection` command. Since the references section is the very last one, I have to store it to the `.aux` file. This'll likely require one extra processing by LaTeX.
5. The last thing is that `sorting` is no longer supported by `\printbibliography`, hence the `\newrefcontext`.

The final code is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{ref1,
title = {An experimental study},
year = {2000},
author = {Smith, M}
}
@article{ref2,
title = {Analysis of topics},
year = {2005},
author = {Johnson, B}
}
@article{ref3,
title = {Methodological review},
year = {2010},
author = {Thompson, R}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee,refsection=chapter,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\newcommand\ReferencesList{}
\newcommand\AddtoRefsList[1]{\xdef\ReferencesList{\ReferencesList,#1}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\AddtoRefsList{\thefield{entrykey}}}

% The following definition is copied from authortitle.bbx/authoryear.bbx
\defbibenvironment{nolabelbib}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@addbackref@i}{\c@refsection}{\c@savedrefsection}{}{}

\newcounter{savedrefsection}
\newcommand\saverefsection{%
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}{\string\setcounter{savedrefsection}{\the\c@refsection}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\cite{ref1} is a new reference and \cite{ref2} as well.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\cite{ref3} is again a new reference that must be numbered as one, while \cite{ref1} first appeared with number one in the previous chapter. Now it must show the number two in the following bibliography.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\newrefsection
\saverefsection
\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]
\nocite{\ReferencesList}

\printbibliography[env=nolabelbib,heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Clever solution. Indeed the OP wants `refsection`s, but the independence makes it hard to compile a complete list of references at the end. Your redefinition of `\cite` has the drawback of making it impossible to use optional arguments though. Maybe you could move the `\AddtoRefsList` to `\AtEveryCitekey`.

Comment: Right, I'll update the answer. Just need some time to find out how to access the citekey in the `\AtEveryCitekey` code. I'm still a bit new in `biblatex` (and excited).

Comment: `\thefield{citekey}`. So you could do something like `\AtEveryCitekey{\AddtoRefsList{\thefield{citekey}}}`.

Comment: Your solution does nearly what I was looking for. `\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]` is not working for me but `sorting=nty` in `\printbibliography` does the trick. Isn't this syntax supported? In addition, would it be possible to include a "(cited at p. 2, 3)" at the last bibliography for `ref1`?

Comment: Ok, I'll answer my previous question. I was using `biblatex` 2.3, I've upgraded to 3.7 and `\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]` is working properly. I'm just wondering how to include the page reference at the alphabetically sorted cites.

Comment: There's the `backref` option for the `biblatex` package, but in your case it'd print the page references for the local bibliographies, and not for the main one (which is understandable as the local bibliographies do the actual citation). I have a dirty trick in mind on how to do that, and will try to implement it a bit later today.

Comment: It looks like `backref=true` is doing the same than `backref=false`. Is it just me?

Comment: It needs two LaTeX passes. One to collect page numbers for all the references, and the second one to use them.

Comment: I run it a couple more than two and unfortunately still remains the same.

Comment: I forgot to add `\saverefsection`. Sorry about that. It's fixed now and should work.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem and it is working like a charm. However, now I've included a `minitoc` and looks like it's interacting with your approach since I'm getting some weird behavior. Removing `minitoc` brings everything back to normality. Any suggestion?