# References/Endnotes And a Bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, endnotes

I need to put in a set of endnotes which are basically all my references. I need it to be ordered numerically as per the citations in my article. Using the code below that's no problem.

I now need to add a bibliography after all the references. I need the bibliography to contain all the sources in my bib file, not just the ones cited, and I need that one to be ordered alphabetically as per a standard bibliography.
I don't know how to do this "second" bibliography with the first one. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
\usepackage[
    %backend=biber, 
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex} %bibliography
\addbibresource{_References.bib}
```

.....

```
% Set up Bibliography
\newpage
\printbibliography
```

Comment: Would faking it be an option? You could create a second master document with the different sort settings. Then, append the bibliography thus generated to your main document using the `pdfpages` package.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/[(MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Ya I was thinking of that as a back up but seems unnecessary. Anyway, see the answer below. Works a treat.

Comment: @gusbrs thanks for your comment, I was just trying to keep things concise, didn't think any other info was necessary but I will keep that in mind for futur thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this meets your requirements, for you didn't give us much specifics. But as far as the question goes, you could try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{nolabelbib} % borrowing from lockstep's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10106/105447
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\autocite{kastenholz,sarfraz,brandt}

\printbibliography

\newrefsection
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\nocite{*}
\AtNextBibliography{\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}}
\printbibliography[env=nolabelbib,title={Bibliography}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent thank you and works perfectly. Really appreciate your help. If you have time, I have one small qs about modifying the second bibliography. Is there a way to remove a particular field, for example, leave out "pages" in the second bib only??

Comment: @gravity121, glad to know it was useful. As to removing particular fields, I suggest you ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117), linking it to this one. As this is a questions and answers site, things work better dealing with one issue at a time. However, I'm not sure how much flexibility will be possible with this approach. Mixing different styles in the same document is not, as far as I know, something biblatex is well equipped to do. But someone might well come up with something.